# Get value from CSV file on specific coordinate

Tags: powershell, csv

I need to extract data from CSV file based on coordinates entered by user, 
so let's say that user enter next values:

```
$rowPosition = 5
$columnName = 'testColumn'
```

and I need to get value from `5th` row in column `testColumn`.

I know how to extract just one column, but I need further filtering with row position.

Comment: It's a good trick, but please put your SOLUTION in an answer, it will avoid people to loose time on an answered question.

Answer (score 1):

First, I created two variables consisting column name and row position in desired CSV file.

```
$columnName = 'testColumn'    
$rowPosition = 2
```

Then I just access to specific cell at this way:

```
#Load .csv file into variable
$csvFile = Import-csv .\Desktop\counter.csv -Delimiter ','

echo $csvFile.$columnName[$rowPosition]
```

Comment: Note that `-Delimiter ','` is redundant as it is the default one used.